# Sending POST request from android to RoR app, but cannot find the right URL

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, server

I am not able to reach the create Method in tests_controller.rb with this code.

```
String newUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/tests";

        httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(newUrl).openConnection()));
        httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpcon.connect();
```

And here is my routes.rb (I use model scaffold to create the RoR app).

```
resources :tests
```

Am i wrong in routing or something. When i run this code in Android, the create method is not run at all.

Comment: are you testing on simulator or real device?

Comment: Check your development logs are actually getting hit.

Comment: I think the problem is that the host (at 10.0.2.2) is in a network that is not reachable from device network

Comment: check the output of `rake routes` in your rails app

Comment: @MladenJablanović It is like this:     
          GET    /tests(.:format)          tests#index
          POST   /tests(.:format)          tests#create

Comment: @ddb i have tried with localhost and 127.0.0.1, they all give me exception, only this 10.0.2.2 not give me anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell the reason for the failure you have. Your routes seem OK. You can check couple other things:

- Is your Rails server listening on the right interface and port?
- Is there any network problem between the machine your client is working on and the server?
- Instead of going through the cycle of edit-compile-deploy-run of Android, simply use `curl` or a similar tool to try the POST request from the console.

When you pinpoint the place of the problem, then you can ask another question, or, more likely, already find the answer online.